# socket.io image directory not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I copied example server code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}
```

When I visit some image file inside images directory it's not showing me the image. How to achieve that? If I try any address there's always content of index.html.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't even attempt to read different files - it's index.html all the time. And it's not clear what's socket.io doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node.js server is hard-coded to only ever return one file `index.html`, not matter what file was requested by the browser.  So, when the browser requests images that may be referenced in `index.html`, then your code just sends back `index.html` again.

Remember, a node.js server does not serve ANY files by default.  So, all files that you wish it to serve must be coded specifically or you can use some helpers (like `Express.static()`) to serve a whole directory of static files.

Plus, socket.io doesn't have anything to do with serving image files so I'm unclear why you linked those two subjects together in the title of your question.

---

FYI, if you use the Express framework for your web server, then you can use `Express.static()` to serve a whole directory of image files with one line of code.  See the [Express doc](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) for details.

Comment: Like @jfriend00 said, express is probably the way to go here. If you want to get a quick server up and running you should use [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator). It will set you up nicely and will contain the static file handling and it will give you a much better idea of the basic structure of an Express app. Plus Socket.io has a [quickstart](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4) for integrating with Express.